# Problems with module path in Python (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named)

Tags: python, macos, python-import, modulenotfounderror

Today I have a problem with module in Python.
My file structure:

```
- library
--- Storage.py
- scripts
--- run.py
```

and run.py code:

```
import library.Storage as Storage
```

but I run this in PyCharm it work fine but if I run in terminal

```
python3 scripts/run.py
```

it return

```
    import library.Storage as Storage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'library'
```

I had tried this

```
fpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(fpath)
print(sys.path)

['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/Users/binhot/PycharmProjects/MyProject/']
```

but the problems still happen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   Did you add a ```__init__.py``` to your ```library``` directory?

Comment: Already add __init__.py in library

Comment: You can 1) move run.py to the directory above "scripts" **or** 2) run the script as a module like this: `python3 -m scripts.run`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/407651.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solve this problems by create `setup.sh`to add current path to PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:`pwd`"
```

now it work fine !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that python is trying to import the module `library` from inside the `scripts` folder. What you need to do is make a relative import. See more here: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#relative-imports

Comment: I had tried this also but still    
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: The parent directory of your library and script directories must also be a package with a \_\_init__.py file